# SSMS - How to have the Date fields format in the user DB language format in the result query without using Convert or Format in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, date, format, ssms

When executing a SQL query in Sql Server Management Studio 18.9.2 (@@version 2016 SP1), I would like to display the info of a datatype "date" in the format of the language of the connected db user, without using FORMAT or Convert in the SQL STATEMENT .
I try to explain myself better.

[image]

As you can see from the image, running DBCC USEROPTIONS, the language is set to Italian and the format is dmy, and it's ok.

The second query in the picture, is an example of how without the use of functions such as FORMAT or CONVERT or CAST I would like it to return to the date format of the DB user by executing it.

So, taking the image as an example, the DtDate field of the SQL query I would like to display as "19/10/2022" (i.e. in the format dd/MM/yyyy) instead of how it is shown ('yyyy-MM-dd').

I have tried the following things:

- install the SMSS package in Italian;
- set in SMSS in Tools->Options-> Environment-> Italian or "Same as Microsoft Windows" (with Regional Settings in Italian);
- DB user language in Italian;

but nothing to do, the date is shown to me in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Instead, I confirm that the conditions of 'where' actually take into account the format dd/MM/yyyy, in fact a SELECT statement with "where DtDate = '19/10/2022' correct rows are selected!

Thank you all for taking the time to read or answer my question

Comment: Honestly, I really wouldn't try to change that; dates like `01/02/2022` are ambiguous. If you want to display it in certain ways in your user application sure let them customise it, but in your IDE an ISO format is *way* better.

Comment: SSMS is not a presentation layer. This is just a formatting preference and as such should be handled in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

All numbers are in algebraic. Except some odd international date formats that use an illogical order and display small to big?
In binary 10 is bigger than 01, and the same in decimal 10 is bigger than 01 *(we do not write the 0 but you can place as many zero's to left as you like the value won't change.)*
So displaying a date from small to big (d-m-y) is unnatural in my opinion.
Nobody uses a time format ***mm:hh***? So why in would anybody even use m-d-y or d-m-y?
The logic is completely missing, there is no other explanation than "I am used to do it that way".

A year is bigger than a month which is bigger than as day.
y-m-d is the most logical order.